# Have 2 buttons affect same label

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to create two buttons using `JFrame` and `ActionListener` that will display a randomly generated array in a label, and sort said array. I've got down the button that will display the randomly generated array, but I'm having trouble with the button that will be sorting it. Is there a way to access the array created with `mybutton4` with the `mybutton3` to accomplish this?

This is what I have for the button that displays a random array of 10 numbers:

```
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("myButton4"))
{
    int[] Array = RandomArray.list();
    String strArray[] = Arrays.stream(Array).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
    label.setText("Array: ["+String.join(",", strArray)+"]");
}
```

If I use something similar but in `button3`, I can get it to output a sorted array, but I need the button to sort the array displayed after clicking `mybutton4`.

This is my code for the sorting button (which just displays a sorted random array):

```
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("myButton2"))
{
    int[] Array = RandomArray.list();
    Arrays.sort(Array);
    String strArray[] = Arrays.stream(Array).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
    label.setText("Array: ["+String.join(",", strArray)+"]");
}
```

Thanks for your comments and help.

Comment: Use one or more instance fields - [Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Comment: within each getActionCommand()?

Comment: No, read the tutorial - learn the difference between local and instance type variables/fields

Comment: I understand the difference between local and instance variables/fields, but since the randomly generated array is being created every time I push button3, how would I be able to affect it from another button.

Comment: `int[] Array = RandomArray.list();` is locally defined variable with the context of the `if` statement that created it.  `Array` (which is a horrible name by the way) needs to be defined as a instance field of the class which wants to use it

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, I get an error message saying that the only modifier permitted for the variable is final

Comment: Without a [mcve], there's not much more we can offer

Comment: Turned out I'm blind and had not defined the variable at all, as you said. Upon modifying it I was able to correct it. Now both buttons work as expected.

Comment: Thank's a lot @MadProgrammer.

Answer (score 1):

Defined the variable in the class as:

```
public int[] getArray;
```

And modified the `getActionCommand` statements for each button accordingly. It now works as expected.

```
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("myButton2"))
{
    int[] sortArray = getArray;
    Arrays.sort(sortArray);
    String strArray[] = Arrays.stream(sortArray).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
    label.setText("Array: ["+String.join(",", strArray)+"]");
}

if(e.getActionCommand().equals("myButton4"))
{
    getArray = RandomArray.list();
    String strArray[] = Arrays.stream(getArray).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
    label.setText("Array: ["+String.join(",", strArray)+"]");
}
```

Thanks to MadProgrammer for pointing out my oversight.

Comment: Plus one for taking the tips of MadProgrammer and developing them into a solution.